# PyQt5 is not installed via pip3 on mac

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pyqt5

I tried to install pyqt5 on Mac (11.1 Big Sur) via pip3.7 but I failed. I downloaded the file of PyQt5 here: https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/#files

And this is my error message:

```
> ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 171, in _merge_into_criterion
    crit = self.state.criteria[name]
KeyError: 'pyqt5-qt'
```

P.S. Actually I have 2 version of python (3.7 and 3.8). Could this be a problem?